In how many ways can 3 boys and 2 girls be seated in a row such that no three boys are together?
In how many ways can 3 boys and 2 girls be seated in a row such that no three boys are together?
My approach:
We can have:
BBFBF
BBFFB
BFBBF
BFBFB
BFFBB
FBFBB
FBBFB
For every group, there are
$3!\times 2! = 12$ ways to arrange them
So, there $12\times 7=84$ ways
Is there an alternative that doesn't require counting and how can I count the seven cases?

Easier (slightly) to count the cases in which all three are together.  There are fewer patterns:  $BBBGG, GBBBG, GGBBB$.

@lulu Yes, this approach is way easier ($5! - 3! * 2! * 3$), but I'm still wondering how can I count these seven cases or even those three.

Are you assuming that the individual boys distinguishable? The girls?

For mine,  you are arranging three things,  the two girls and the block of boys.  Clearly there are three ways to do that. No need to list them, though listing them is easy

@SammyBlack Yes, they should be distinguishable

Expanding on @lulu's comment, and assuming that the individual boys (resp., girls) are distinguishable, we should enumerate the complementary set of arrangements where the three boys are together.
For this, first treat all three boys as a single block, so we count permutations of $\{B, G_1, G_2\}$, where $B$ is shorthand for the block of $3$ consecutive boys. Then, for each such permutation, we can rearrange the $3$ boys freely, so the total count is $3! \cdot 3!$.
Now, there are $5!$ total permutations of the $5$ people, without restrictions, so the answer is
$$
5! - 3! \cdot 3! = 120 - 6 \cdot 6 = 84.
$$

The generalization of this with $b$ boys and $g$ girls is (try it yourself before revealing!)

 $$ (b + g)! - (g + 1)! \cdot b! $$


Your generalization means that all boys are not together. (Though you answer is wrong for $b = 0$.) However generalization would be much more interesting if we keep condition that no three boys are together.

@Smylic That's fair. I should have been more clear in how I was generalizing: enumerating arrangements where all boys are not together. And yes, it only works when there's at least $1$ boy. In fact, that case is kind of daft too, but the formula predicts the correct number: $0$.
